Repeated calls to console.log in Safari 17 give no output
When I call console.log(1, 'foo') in Safari 17's Javascript console it prints 1 and "foo" as expected after the first call but then the second call prints nothing as seen below.

When console.log is called with the arguments in reverse order (or other argument combinations such as (number), (string), (number, number), etc.) subsequent calls print identically as I would expect.

This behavior is different from Chrome and Firefox which behave as expected. I am curious if this is a webkit bug or if there is some wiggle room in the Javascript console specification (see here https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#log) resulting in this behavioral difference between Safari and other browsers.
